# How can Java Write/Read hardware ports like C does? (outb, inb etc..)

Tags: java, hardware-port

I've a C application. This application writes and reads some I/O port addresses.

I think that Java can't access low level I/O address natively. Am I right?

Here is an example of C++ app:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/io.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Refresh watchdog program" << endl;

    outb(0x87,0x2E);     //Extended Function Mode
    outb(0x30,0x2E);     //Set Watch Dog Timer Activate
    outb(0x01,0x2F);
    int reg = inb(0x2f);
    outb(reg|0x08, 0x2f);

}
```

How can I do the same in Java?

Comment: Write some JNI to do it for you

Comment: I am not sure if this is entirely related, but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925489/pc-hardware-port-access-from-java-on-linux) link

Comment: [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/207196/do-pointers-really-exist-in-java)

Comment: You *could* also accomplish it via `sun.misc.Unsafe` possibly, but I didn't advice that.

Comment: People talking about unsafe are I believe correct; although it is called "unsafe" for a reason and is undocumented by design. What are you trying to achieve? There is usually a better way to achieve things that going through the dark arts

Comment: This is not memory access. This is I/O port access, and I/O ports are not the same as memory. You can't access them even with sun.misc.Unsafe, and I didn't know you could access them outside the kernel at all. You will need to use JNI or find a pre-existing library (that uses JNI). (Edit: This depends on the architecture. x86 processors have a separate concept of I/O ports, but this might not be one)

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960620/low-level-i-o-access-using-outb-and-inb

Comment: @immibis The `inb` and `outb` functions can be called outside of the kernel, but they require special permissions.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925489/pc-hardware-port-access-from-java-on-linux

Answer (score 4):

I think sun.misc.Unsafe might help you for this. It has methods like `void putAddress(long address, long value)` that may suit your need. To be honest I haven't worked on this but you could know more about it from

http://mydailyjava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/sunmiscunsafe.html

http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/

A small sample program could be found on

http://robaustin.wikidot.com/how-to-write-to-direct-memory-locations-in-java

Comment: This is a totally different type of I/O.  It's not memory access that `Unsafe` would be able to do.